# Counter that keeps its value even after closing the program vb?

Tags: vb.net, function, counter

How can I declare a counter that keeps its value even after I close the program?

Using `static` keeps the value as long as the program is working, but when I close it, the value goes back to zero. I want to keep this value.

This is my function:

```
Function counter() As Long
    Static total As Decimal = 20160500
    total += 1
    Return total
End Function
```

Comment: You need to write your value on a file and the read it back when your program restarts. (There is also the option to use a configuration entry in your AppSettings section of the config file)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc6ws923.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Create a setting to store the value. It'll get saved in an automatically chosen location so you don't have to worry about files. Go to Project -> ... Properties -> Settings and add one to the list with its initial value (20160500). Then refer to it in code as `My.Settings.Total`

```
Function counter() As Long
    My.Settings.Total += 1
    Return My.Settings.Total
End Function
```

You might also need to explicitly save the settings when the program exits, but I think this gets done automatically.

```
My.Settings.Save()
```